# Angular 2 calling api on component load

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am pretty new to angular 2, what I am trying to accomplish is simple:

1. Get the category id passed in via routing
2. Call API with category id
3. Populate variable "category" with data returned from API and display the category name

My view is simple:

```
<h3>{{category.name}}</h3>
```

Component code:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'browse-category',
    template: require('./browse-category.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./browse-category.component.css')]
})
export class BrowseCategoryComponent {
    products: IProduct[];
    category: ICategory;
    categoryId: number;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: Http, @Inject('ORIGIN_URL') private originUrl: string) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.categoryId = +params['categoryId']; 
            // get category details
            this.http.get(this.originUrl + '/api/Category/' + this.categoryId).subscribe(result => {
                var data = result.json().data;
                if (data != null && result.status === 200) {
                    this.category = data;
                    console.log(this.category);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

If I disable the view output, i am able to see the console.log output, if I don't I get the following error:

NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

I assume it's because the promise hasn't returned yet. Ideally what's the best approach to fix this?

Comment: What is the console.log output?

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{category?.name}}`
This is called the "safe navigation" operator and with it angular will only try to access category if it is defined and not null.

Comment: The Elvis operator is actually `?:`.  This is the ["safe navigation" operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-operators).